# How to make a report in which every page has different structure?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to export a report in pdf in which every page has different structure. How to accomplish this in *JasperReports* since we make a report template and then the data gets filled in the report according to the template.

Comment: Do you want that header of every page would be different or something else?

Comment: page header and page footer will be same

Comment: its depends upon content whatever you fill in detail band print on page.does you have specfic data that will ont cross one page.

Comment: i already said in question that pdf will have multiple pages. every page will have static content and/or dynamic content and structure of every page is different

Comment: @Guru You can try this solution: [Exporting Multiple Reports into a Single Output File (Batch Export)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with subreports.
In main report add a subreport in a details band and set Subreport Expression to choose which subreport to display based on current row values.
Something like:

```
$F{WHICH_SUBREPORT} == 1 
     ?  "repo:sub1.jrxml"
     : $F{WHICH_SUBREPORT} == 2
       ? "repo:sub2.jrxml"
       : "repo:sub3.jrxml"
```